# How to send push notifications to iOS using a python api

Tags: python, iphone, push-notification

I have create a webscraper that sends notifications to my phone whenever certain events are detected. So far I have achieved this by sending emails through the sendgrid api. Its a pretty nice service, and it is free, but it clutters up the mailbox quite a bit.

In stead I’d like to send messages directly to the iOS notification bar. Does anyone here has experience with sending push-notifications to iOS and can point me in the correct direction? I would be happy with a subscription service, but would off course prefer a solution that does not require a third party if it is possible.

I have tested PushNotifier, but I found it a bit clunky, and the notifications are neither customisable or beautiful. Its also not a free service, which would have been a great plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should check out pushover.net. They have a simple WebAPI to send customized notifications to iOS devices.

See https://support.pushover.net/i44-example-code-and-pushover-libraries#python for code samples.

Comment: Thanks for that. Upon closer inspection I see that pushover.net is exactly what I was looking for =)